# Find element then append in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically create html element, but when trying to append some element inside the container in loop it is not working. Why?

```
var html = '<div id="' + question.id + '"> \
                <div class="quizlib-question">  \
                    <div class="well well-sm quizlib-question-title"><strong>' + question.title + '</strong></div>  \
                    <div class="quizlib-question-answers"></div> \
                </div> \
            </div>';

for (var i=0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
    var answerHTML = '<div class="radio quizlib-question-answer"><label><input type="radio" name="' + question.name + '" value="' + i + '">' + question.choices[i] + '</label></div>';
    //this part is nor working
    $(html).find(".quizlib-question-answers").append(answerHTML);
}

$('body').append(html);
```

Comment: You are appending the `answerHtml` to a jQuery object which contains the `html` variable, but you never append that to the DOM, hence nothing actually appears to happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$(html).find(".quizlib-question-answers").append(answerHTML);
```

does **not** update the string variable `html`, it appends to a jQuery object which has been created initially with the contents of `html`.

To fix this, append the jQuery object to the dom, not `html`. Start by creating the jQuery object initially

```
var $html = $('<div id="' + question.id + '"> \
            <div class="quizlib-question">  \
                <div class="well well-sm quizlib-question-title"><strong>' + question.title + '</strong></div>  \
                <div class="quizlib-question-answers"></div> \
            </div> \
        </div>');
```

(Note, I prefix jQuery objects with `$` by convention)

Then append as normal:

```
for (var i=0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
    var answerHTML = '<div class="radio quizlib-question-answer"><label><input type="radio" name="' + question.name + '" value="' + i + '">' + question.choices[i] + '</label></div>';
    //this part is nor working
    $html.find(".quizlib-question-answers").append(answerHTML);
}
```

Finally add that to the DOM

```
$('body').append($html);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because you are appending `html` to the DOM, yet you never update the `html` variable. Instead you're creating a jQuery object from that variable, but you never do anything with it.

To fix this, try creating a jQuery object from `html` immediately and then append that to the DOM before doing your loop, like this:

```
var $html = $('<div id="' + question.id + '"> \
    <div class="quizlib-question">  \
        <div class="well well-sm quizlib-question-title"><strong>' + question.title + '</strong></div>  \
        <div class="quizlib-question-answers"></div> \
    </div> \
</div>').appendTo('body');

for (var i = 0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
    var answerHTML = '<div class="radio quizlib-question-answer"><label><input type="radio" name="' + question.name + '" value="' + i + '">' + question.choices[i] + '</label></div>';
    $html.find(".quizlib-question-answers").append(answerHTML);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/557h3dxf/)

Comment: Near as dammit, I prefer yours to mine as it has one less step!

Comment: Yours is probably quicker though as you append from the loop in memory :)

Comment: and @Jamiec yours only hits the DOM once

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenter mentioned, you have to append to the body before you start searching for those DOM elements you created. For example:

```
var html = '<div id="' + question.id + '"> \
                <div class="quizlib-question">  \
                    <div class="well well-sm quizlib-question-title"><strong>' + question.title + '</strong></div>  \
                    <div class="quizlib-question-answers"></div> \
                </div> \
            </div>';
$('body').append(html);

for (var i=0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
    var answerHTML = '<div class="radio quizlib-question-answer"><label><input type="radio" name="' + question.name + '" value="' + i + '">' + question.choices[i] + '</label></div>';
    //this part is nor working
    $(".quizlib-question-answers").append(answerHTML);
}
```